# How to know if the system clock has changed?

Tags: android, time, timezone

In my application I have a service that after for example 30 seconds, runs another activity. I did this process with Alarm Manager.

But the problem is, if the user changes the system time it affects 30 seconds. What is your suggestion? Is there any way to know if the user changes the system time?

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

It looks like it will make your life a whole lot easier. I know I'm 7 months late, but just in case you run into the problem again, the document will be useful. Basically, `SystemClock` allows you to measure elapsed time, rather than having to rely on the system's wall clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to `Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` broadcast. Your ApplicationManifest file should contain something like

```
    <receiver android:name="com.test.YouBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For broadcast receivers refer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Also, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED actions may be of interest here.